# Any “Link Preview” (like the facebook feature) in joomla editor?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, editor

I'm writing articles commenting diverse sources from the web (youtube video/news articles, blogs...). 
To show which article I'm commenting I'm using an image (thumbnail + some text). So my article looks a little bite like a facebook post: the "link preview" (basically an image) is shown on the side of my comment about this source.

How a link preview works: you dropped an URL in your editing box (example your Facebook post or leocardz code) and it automatically fetch the title some text and build a thumbnail of the article.

A link preview looks like this:

[image]

For the moment I'm using either:

- the Facebook "link preview" feature to generate the link preview, (I
  screen-shot the link preview and use the image in my article)
- or a better alternative: the a great [leocardz code](http://lab.leocardz.com/facebook-link-preview-php--jquery/) to generate
  the link preview (used as a screen-shot).

To use leocardz code I just dropped his folder into my ftp, and access this link preview when I need it. Since I did not find a way to make leocardz code working inside JCE I need to screenshot the link preview (that theoretically could be done automatically by the editor).

I am surprised I couldn't find this link preview in any plugin. I find it strange because it's an essential a basic social media function (when you past an URL into your post you expect it to show a preview of your link) and because the code is available.

Do you know any Joomla plugin /editor that support link preview?

Comment: So what exactly are you asking for here? For someone to write all the code for a plugin? Even if you feel you can't write a small plugin, at least give it a go. We all have to start somewhere, and yes, it sometimes also take time

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear enough. I have edited it. Actually I am looking for an editor/plugin that would do it. I did talk about that non Joomla plugin to show that this kind of feature does exist outside Facebook

Comment: For it work in JCE you would need to create a JCE plugin not a Joomla plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I checked [Joomla Extensions - Article Preview](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/authoring-a-content/article-preview) and found 4 plugins and a component/plugin that appear to do what you're looking for.

With your clarification, I wouldn't expect this to be an easy plugin to write - certainly not a generic preview as each site with content to preview would package it differently, and the plugin would have to understand how to find the content you're looking for

Comment: On the link you provided, I couldn't find a plugin that generate a preview of an external page (no hosted on my Joomla website), but only of an internal article (the article of my Joomla website).

Comment: @arone : my mistake, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

To do that you need an open graph plugin, you can use this one https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/tagz-open-graph/ , I used in one of my sites.